# Convert session.lastAccessedTime into javascript date object

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to convert `session.lastAccessedTime` object from `jsp` into `Javascript Date object`. Currently, it displays as long object. How can I convert to Javascript date object?

```
console.log('MaxInactive Interval ==  ' +  ${pageContext.session.lastAccessedTime});
```

Comment: have you tried `new Date(lastAccessedTime)`?

Comment: did you use this  - `Date.parse(lastAccessedTime)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.parse()` method to convert `date string` to `date object`.

[MDN Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

The `Date.parse()` method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC

`Date.parse(lastAccessedTime)`